# Bluebird .then(): not working as it should

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, promise, bluebird

I just started working with promises and Bluebird. While debugging I can see that my function is executed twice:

First I get this error: `TypeError: Uncaught error: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`

Then I see the function is executed again, and `.then()` is executed successfully. Also I get the correct information printed in the console.

Why is this happening? The whole reason I'm implementing promises is because I want to wait with executing the `then()`-action, because my data has to be retrieved first. But still the code jumps to the .then() action too early.

Why is this happening and how can I prevent it?

Here's my code:

```
exports.findUser = function(userId){

    var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
    var u_id = new ObjectID(userId);

    db.collection('users')
        .findOne({'_id': u_id})
        .then(function(docs) { //executed twice, first time error, second time success
            console.log(docs); //prints correct info once executed
            return docs;
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
};
```

Comment: If you promisified it, did you mean to write `findOneAsync`?

Comment: `TypeError: Uncaught error: db.collection(...).findOneAsync is not a function`

Comment: Did you `Promise.promisifyAll(require("mongoose"))` ?

Comment: Where exactly should I put that line?

Comment: `var mongoose = Promise.promisifyAll(require("mongoose"))`

Comment: Ok, result is still the same: `TypeError: Uncaught error: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined'`

Comment: How can I prevent it from going to .then() when the first query is not finished?

Answer (score 1):

When working with the native npm module you should use callbacks here, like in the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb#find-all-documents). So for your example this would mean:

```
exports.findUser = function(userId){

    var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
    var u_id = new ObjectID(userId);

    db.collection('users')
        .findOne({'_id': u_id}, function(err, docs){
            console.log(docs); //prints correct info once executed
            return docs;
        });
};
```

If you want to use promises than maybe you should consider using something like [mongoose](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose).